# How do I disable the click handler on a YUI Node?

Tags: javascript, dom, yui

I am wanting to be able to disable the click functionality of a radio button so I can uncheck it.

However, when I uncheck it, the click still fires and the end result is a radio that unselects (and modifies other page elements accordingly), and then re-checks because of the onclick event.

```
    var clickFunction = function(e, radio, p){
        var checked = radio.get("checked");
        radio.set("checked", !checked);
    };
    this.controlNode = Y.Node.create("<input id='" + id + "' onclick='function(e){return false;}' type='radio' name='" + parent.id + "'>");
    this.label = Y.Node.create("<label for='" + id + "'>" + display + "</label>");
    Y.on("mousedown", clickFunction, this.label, this.controlNode, parent.controlNode);
    parent.controlNode.appendChild(this.controlNode);
    parent.controlNode.appendChild(this.label);
```

The mousedown event handler is used, as it's for fat fingers on a (windows) touch screen, and movement between mousedown and mouseup does not constitute a click.  (Throughout a tap with a finger, the finger will increase and decrease it's surface area on the screen, and a non-multitouch screen put the cursor at the average of the contact points.  A slight roll will move the cursor).

The mouse down bubbles up, and results in dependency evaluation and show/hiding other controls on a page.

I simply want undo; and I think that having another reset option is less than satisfactory for my particular use.  If nothing else eventuates here, I shall have to use that.

Comment: @Roatin - don't worry.  I had a hard time trying to make this question clear enough to answer. It's a strange issue - only one item should be selected, so a radio is appropriate.  However, because of event propagation, it is not enough to clear the "checked" variable, as events need to bubble so that other event listeners know the control has changed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`halt` method](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/DOMEventFacade.html#method_halt) on the event facade passed to your event handler:

```
this.controlNode = Y.Node.create("<input id='" + id + "' type='radio' name='" + parent.id + "'>");
this.controlNode.on("click", function(e) { e.halt(); });
```

This will stop the event propagating and the default event behaviour (the click).

Comment: Once you get your parameters in order, I can accept :)... almost.

The interesting thing is that even with the id param after the function, it will not work, as my input control is display none, and the click is on the label (button-styled).  So the click handler needs to be on that.  Since it's only one control, you can do Y.on('click', function(e) {...}, this.label); or even this.label.on('click', function(e) {...})

Comment: Your radio input is not displayed!?

Comment: Oh, right, the event handler parameter order switched from YUI 2 to 3.

Comment: Yes - I hide my radio input... regardless, it's something that needs to be considered when you have <label for="id"/> elements, as their on click is not "transferred" to the input element.  So in a normal situation where both are visible, you need to handle the onclick on both.